# Bootstrap - Error in the style of the accordion with php

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table of categories in my database and I am generating a menu from it. I can generate the menu perfectly this way:

```
$renderItems = function($items) use (&$renderItems)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo h($item->name);

        if ($item->children) {
            $renderItems($item->children);
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
};

$renderItems($list);
```

I'm trying to style this menu in the bootstrap accordion format, but I find it difficult to generate the child items correctly.

The menu looks like this:

[image]

with this code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">

                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="padding: 0px">
                        Menu 1
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px">
                        <li><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> SubMenu 1</li>
                        <hr>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> SubMenu 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to solve it this way, but I believe there is something wrong.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <?php
        $renderItems = function($items) use (&$renderItems)
        {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo '<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">';
                echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="padding: 0px">';

                echo h($item->nome);
                echo '</button>';
                echo '</h5>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">';

                if ($item->children) {

                    echo '<div class="card-body">';
                    echo '<ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px">';
                    echo '<li>';
                    $renderItems($item->children);
                    echo '</li>';
                    echo '</ul>';                            
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
              }
          };
          $renderItems($list);
          ?>

          </div>
</div>
```

Can a friend tell me how to organize this or what am I doing wrong? I appreciate any comments. The end result looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap pays attention to html attributes. You should too. So;

You can change and try again. *(They are should dynamic values your loop for basic solve)*; `headingOne`, `collapseOne`.

If you test the fiction before looping, you will see the problem yourself.

Also this expression is `class ="collapse show"`; brings all elements opened. If you want, you may want to add a "show" to the first element.

[Bootstrap 4 - collapse documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/)